# How to populate a custom listview from .txt file ? Android Studio

Tags: android, file, listview, text, populate

trying to populate a custom listview from a .txt file.

The custom listview have 2 lines, Maintitle and Subtitle.

this is what i tried :

In the MainActivity.java :

```
public void readTxt() {

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyApp/file.txt";
        File file = new File( path );
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( file ) );
            String line;

            while ((line = br2.readLine()) != null) {

                    String[] maintitle = {
                            line
                    };

                    String[] subtitle = {
                            line
                    };

                    MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter( this, maintitle, subtitle );
                    lv = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.lv );
                    lv.setAdapter( adapter );

                }

          br2.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText( this, "Error loading playlist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    }
}
```

In MyListAdapter.java :

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] maintitle;
    private final String[] subtitle;


    public MyListAdapter(Activity context, String[] maintitle, String[] subtitle) {

       super(context, R.layout.lv_player, maintitle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context=context;
        this.maintitle=maintitle;
        this.subtitle=subtitle;

    }

    public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_player, null,true);

        TextView titleText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.maintitle);
        TextView subtitleText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);

        titleText.setText(maintitle[position]);
        subtitleText.setText(subtitle[position]);

        return rowView;

    };
}
```

My .txt file looks like this : 
Apple, think different, Nokia, connecting people, Huawei, Make it Possible

With this code only first item is populated, how to populate all ?

Comment: There is a problem with your `while`. The `ListView`'s adapter will change every time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a method to your Adapter that set content and to pass there all information from your file?

It might look like this

Adapter:

```
...
 public MyListAdapter(Activity context) {
       super(context, R.layout.lv_player, maintitle);

       this.context=context;
    }
... 
public void setContent (String[] titleFromAfile, String [] subtitleFromAfile){
       maintitle = titleFromAfile
       subtitle = subtitleFromAfile
}
```

Activity:

```
while (){
...
}

MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter( this);
                    lv = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.lv );
                    lv.setAdapter( adapter )

adapter.setContent(mainTitle, subTitle);
```

Don't forget to append arrays